# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" ArrayList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

People, I need your help with this issue because I cannot find the proper solution to solve it.

the issue is:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.maimonides.www.progmul3.tps.tp1.Garage.park(Garage.java:57)
    at edu.maimonides.www.progmul3.tps.tp1.GarageElPlus.main(Garage.java:29)
Java Result: 1**
```

// Translation: Auto = Car - Moto = Motorcicle - Camioneta = Van

```
**Class Park Slot**

public class Park Slot {


  private ArrayList<Integer> bigParkSlot =  
       new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11));
   private ArrayList<Integer> avaliableParkSlot =  
       new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
              11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22));
   private Map<Integer, String> busyParkSlot = new HashMap<>();
   private ArrayList uncoveredParkSlot =  
       new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
   private ArrayList coveredParkSlot = 
       new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

   }

   **Class Garage**  

    // Line 57
    // the problem is here

   ArrayList<Integer> pElem = c.getavaliableParkSlot();

   int num = pElem.iterator().next();
```

Comment: My guess would be that `c` is *null* and when you call `getavaliableParkSlot()` on this, its throwing you the error

Comment: this is what debuggers are for.  place a breakpoint on line 57, and press debug in your IDE.  see what `c` is.  Otherwise, everything we say is *psychic debugging* where we just try to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue so quickly here:

```
private Park Slot c;
```

The solution is here:

```
private Park Slot c = new Park Slot();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is variable `c` assigned? It's probably null.

Comment: in the class Garage

private Park Slot c;

Comment: that is where it is *Declared*.  assigned would mean `c = [something here, probably beginning with "new"];`